# Missing character in ASCII table - Java

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii

I created an ASCII table in Java that prints 10 characters per line, and goes from '!' to '~'. Everything worked great except for the first row, which only printed nine characters (or printed a space?). Does anyone see a syntax or processing problem that would be causing this? It only happened on the first row. 
Note: I was only allowed to use one for loop.

```
public class AsciiChars {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        int count = 0; // initialize counter variable

        for (int ascii = 33; ascii < 127; ascii++, count++) { //conditions for the for loop

            if ((ascii - 12) % 10 == 0){ //formula needed to create the rows. The end char in each row,
                                         // minus 12 (42, 52, 62, etc), will be divisible by 10, thus ending the row.
            System.out.println("\n"); // Print a new line after every row.
        } //end if
            System.out.print((char)ascii + " "); //casting the ascii int to a char and adding a space after every char
        }//end for loop
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: What were you expecting to see?

Answer (score 1):

Your math is correct in that it will decide to print a newline character on the 10th character (#42).  However, you print the newline first, before you print the character, so only 9 characters made it to the first line.  The 10th through 19th characters are printed on the second line, etc.

Move the newline printing line and associated `if` statement after the print of the current character.

Also, `println` will already print a newline character after the string it's passed as a parameter.  You can just call `println()`.

Comment: I should have known better with not needing the "\n" in the print statement. It was 4am while I was coding it up. Haha.

Comment: But yes, that was a syntactical oversight on my part with having the new line before the char print. That fixed it. I appreciate your help @rgettman

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like

```
for (int ascii = 33; ascii < 127; ascii++, count++) { //conditions for the for loop

    System.out.print((char)ascii + " "); //casting the ascii int to a char and adding a space after every char

    if ((ascii - 12) % 10 == 0){ //formula needed to create the rows. The end char in each row,
                                 // minus 12 (42, 52, 62, etc), will be divisible by 10, thus ending the row.
        System.out.println("\n"); // Print a new line after every row.
    } //end if
}//end for loop
```

Because you are currently going to the next line before printing out the tenth character on the first line.